# i cant save smoke effect(fire) of my blender animation

Tags: animation, export

i made a flame animation by using smoke effect with UVSphere. everything is okey when i am in blender. but i wanna use this animation in unity3D. But when i exported the animation .fbx, I can see only UVSphere not flames. You can see the image below what i meant.

I wanna use this animation in Unity3D. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: You can't export particles and smoke simulation, you have to create a particle system in Unity.

Comment: thank you this is the way i m going to do